# Are ultra high racers available commercially?

Tags: recumbent

In the Hessian woods today I saw a recumbent where the rider was positioned very high; his entire body was higher than any of the wheels.  In this position, he was at least as visible as an rider on an upright bicycle, and more visible that one on a ducking bicycle.  Is such an "ultra high racer" (as opposed to ordinary high racer or low racer) available commercially or may I have been witnessing a custom built / modified bike?

Unfortunately I didn't manage to take a picture, recumbent cyclists are fast :-)

Comment: Can you sketch the rough shape from memory and add to the question?

Comment: I think it was something like this: http://i.imgur.com/vWBhsxE.jpg but I'm not sure because it was quite quick and may not have seen it right (I would have deleted the question if you hadn't answered it already)

Comment: I'd just call that a high racer, with a 700c rear and a 20" front wheel.  The suspension fork means its more for comfort than speed, as does the Underseat Steering which is less aero because it is wider.

Comment: @Criggie Underseat steering, aha!  I was wondering, where is the handlebar :-O

Answer (score 2):

This is a low racer:
[image]
The frame goes lower than the wheel's axles, and as a result the rider's shoulders are somewhere near even with the top of the wheel.  In extreme cases, the rider's head looks to almost rest on the back tyre.  It can be very hard to see forward from these positions, but its the most aero.

This is a high racer:
[image: https://cj0mybydzl-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/high-racer-recumbent-front-wheel-drive-1024x683.jpg]
The lowest part on the frame is above the wheel's axle line.  Rider has a better view forward, but has a higher frontal area to catch the wind.

I'm not aware of anything higher than the high racer design.